# Joomla 2.5 component realization

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, components, joomla2.5

I'm php programmist, and I never wrote components on Joomla **2.5** CMS, but I know it's concepts and some base hierarchy. Now I have to write a booking component which concept is

- to realize the user editable booking form
- to realize the administration of it's data
- to afford admin creating multiple instances of that form (with some different settings e.g. font color, enableness of some fields, ...)
- to afford admin load created instances of form in different materials on site (I suppose by inserting {loadmodule com_name?formid=...} ?)

I see that problem completely hard because of simply unknowing of Joomla inside construction.
How should I implement that? (I mean exacly structure of my component, maybe I should use some hard features, additional plugins, modules, or some special joomla core exceptions ...)? The most important thing is two last steps above. I just can't google how to combine those things in single component on that CMS.

Comment: There are already a bunch of booking components. I'd just get one of those and then if you are not satisfied with it, fork it to add new features for your client.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, your question can be only answered if someone gives you live instructions about Joomla!, ha..ha... apart from jock here are some useful links for you:

- [Developing an MVC Component with Joomla 3](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component)
- [Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/), from here you can find some event & booking extensions already made by famous and trusted developers from Joomla! community.

Let me know if you need specific assistance.

Thanks,
Mrunal